# DatePicker in Kotlin showing wrong month

Tags: android, kotlin

When implementing **Datepicker** in `kotlin` instead of `July` its showing `M07` in all devices.

[image]

Here is code for Date Picker:

```
val c = Calendar.getInstance()
val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(activity, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth -> //differnce(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year, false) }, year, month, day) datePickerDialog.show()
```

Comment: please refer this https://tutorialwing.com/android-datepicker-using-kotlin-example/ or post your code.

Comment: post your code of datepicker here

Comment: Same thing I am getting M07 instead of July

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: val c = Calendar.getInstance()
            val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(activity,
                    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                        //differnce(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year, false)

                    }, year, month, day)
            datePickerDialog.show()

Comment: I see this when the Locale gets messed up in the emulator sometimes. Try picking a new locale in the regular android settings page (not the "Custom Locale" tool) or wiping the emulator and doing a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It’s unreadable in the comment. Instead [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51490354/edit) and add your code there, nicely formatted. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
datebtn.setOnClickListener {
            val c= Calendar.getInstance()
            val year= c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            var dpd = DatePickerDialog(this,DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, mYear,mMonth , mDay ->
                val mmMonth = mMonth+1
                val date = "$mDay/$mmMonth/$mYear"
                datetv.setText(date)
            },year,month,day)
            dpd.show()
        }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! You should try and leave useful information rather than just dumping code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var button_date: Button? = null
var textview_date: TextView? = null
var cal = Calendar.getInstance()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // get the references from layout file
    textview_date = this.text_view_date_1
    button_date = this.button_date_1

    textview_date!!.text = "--/--/----"

    // create an OnDateSetListener
    val dateSetListener = object : DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int,
                               dayOfMonth: Int) {
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            updateDateInView()
        }
    }

    // when you click on the button, show DatePickerDialog that is set with OnDateSetListener
    button_date!!.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(view: View) {
            DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity,
                    dateSetListener,
                    // set DatePickerDialog to point to today's date when it loads up
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
        }

    })
}

private fun updateDateInView() {
    val myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" // mention the format you need
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
    textview_date!!.text = sdf.format(cal.getTime())
}
```

[image]

**show calendar like this please try**

Comment: Same issue with this.

Comment: If same code implement in other project working fine, but in which i want in that its behaving different.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

`{ view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth -> //differnce(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year, false) }`

With

`{ view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                this.year = year
                this.month = monthOfYear
                this.dayOfMonth = dayOfMonth}`