# Why DatePickerDialog title shows wrong month name?

Tags: android

My problem is DatePickerDialog not sowing full month name. please give me answer of my question.

```
try {
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    strStartDate = Utils.getFormattedDate(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year, Constants.YYYY_MM_DD, "dd-M-yyyy");
                    strStartDateDB = Utils.getFormattedDate(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year, Constants.MMM_YYYY, "dd-M-yyyy");
                    Log.e("Date_Api", "" + strStartDate + "-" + strStartDateDB);
                    mBinding.tvStartDate.setText(Utils.getFormattedDate(strStartDate, Constants.DD_MM_YYYY, Constants.YYYY_MM_DD));
                    mBinding.tvStartDate.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black_1));
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    if (!strStartDate.isEmpty()) {
        c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    if (strEndDate.isEmpty()) {
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    } else {
        c.set(mEndYear, mEndMonth, mEndDay);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
    }
    datePickerDialog.show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    AppLog.showLogE("Calendar_exception" + e.getMessage());
}
```

now result is

[image: a busy cat]

I expect result like "Feb 11,Thu And 2019 Feb"

Comment: There's similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490354/datepicker-in-kotlin-showing-wrong-month It has no answer, but there's comment: "I see this when the Locale gets messed up in the emulator sometimes. Try picking a new locale in the regular android settings page (not the "Custom Locale" tool) or wiping the emulator and doing a fresh install." Can you try it?

Comment: set breakpoints and see what value gets assigned to your month variable so that we can assess where the problem begins

Comment: Have you tried running the app on a real device? Sometimes, the emulator misplaces the language of the datepicker

Comment: Can you try creating your datepicker without passing the year,month and date. It will by default pick the current date.

Comment: Did you try it on another device/emulator?

Comment: Already i try many device dear, but output is same.

Answer (score 1):

Put this top of try block

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "GB");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

Comment: Your welcome bro, if your problem is solved so please accept my answer.

Comment: Hello dear one more problem this code show image 2019 M02 header, please give me solution.

Answer (score 1):

Found the easiest solution for this (actually not a solution its an error that resulted in this type of problem).
Your DatePickerDialog not getting the default locale hence it's showing some weird Month selection title. Just set the default locale for English or any other language you want to set for your application.

```
  //call this method in every acitivity before 
//  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 setLanguage(this, "en);
// (change "en" as per your language)




   public static void setLanguage(Context context, String language) {
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.setLocale(new Locale(language, "in")); // API 17+ only.
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, 
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,                
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());*/
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Given the code snippet, log and check these lines of code:

```
  strStartDate = Utils.getFormattedDate(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year, Constants.YYYY_MM_DD, "dd-M-yyyy");
                strStartDateDB = Utils.getFormattedDate(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year, Constants.MMM_YYYY, "dd-M-yyyy");
                Log.e("Date_Api", "" + strStartDate + "-" + strStartDateDB);
                mBinding.tvStartDate.setText(Utils.getFormattedDate(strStartDate, Constants.DD_MM_YYYY, Constants.YYYY_MM_DD));
                mBinding.tvStartDate.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black_1));
```

Answer (score -1):

this is used code try this friend

```
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DateDialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                    0, 0, 0);
            long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            if (startTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                toast(getResources().getString(R.string.select_valid_date));
            } else {
                String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                getDataByDate(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
                getParentActivity().setHomeTabIcon(true);
            }
        }
    }, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
//    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    dialog.show();
```